# How do we handle faster microservices that may process events quicker and produce new events sooner than slower microservices in event sourcing

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

If I have 2 microservices that produce events where one is sometimes faster while the other is slower. In order to ensure deterministic replay in the system is the solution to use a central sequencer to record the events as and when it is produced.

Trying to create a distributed microservices architecture

Comment: Please provide more clarification on the system, including:
- One of the service is "sometimes" faster: Is it faster only in spikes or generally performs faster.
- The objective of the replay: Is it to re feed data into the 2nd slower service or has additional usecases. If it is for the second service, what is the expectation for event persistence, as in does it require permanent persistence or is it expected for a specific time period.